# Spring @Async method calles from @Transactional method isn't asynchronic when it's in a same service

Tags: java, spring

I would like to call some method with delay of some time. Probably this can be achieved in many ways.
My idea was to call @Async method and put there a thread sleep.
Any other solution welcome.
With my solution i have a question could someone explain it to me why in spring method defined in the same service and annotated as @async doesn't work as supposed to work - asynchronous?

```
@Service
public class SomeService {
    @Autowired
    private OtherService otherService;

    @Transactional
    public void someMethod(){
      System.out.println("### ### someMethod before "+  LocalDateTime.now());
      doSomething();
      System.out.println("### ### someMethod before "+  LocalDateTime.now());
    }

    @Transactional
    public void someMethod2(){
      System.out.println("### ### someMethod2 before "+  LocalDateTime.now());
      otherService.doSomething();
      System.out.println("### ### someMethod2 before "+  LocalDateTime.now());
    }

    @Async
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("### ### doSomething before "+  LocalDateTime.now());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(15000L);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("### ### doSomething after "+  LocalDateTime.now());
    }
}

@Service
public class OtherService {
    @Async
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("### ### doSomething before "+  LocalDateTime.now());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(15000L);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("### ### doSomething after "+  LocalDateTime.now());
    }
}
```

So someMethod2 works as expected but someMethod doesn't.

Comment: did you add @EnableAsync and \@EnableScheduling to one of your configuration class ?

Comment: You can find the answer in that attached link